# Concrete mathematics: Computing the value of certain infinite sums example

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, Patashnik), on page 58, there is the below example of calculating the value of an infinite sum :

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} &= \sum_{k \geq 0} k^{\underline{-2}} \\
 &= \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sum_{k=0}^{n} k^{-2} = \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \frac{k^\underline{-1}}{-1}\Biggr|_0^n = 1
\end{align}
$$

For that last part I don't understand how it is $1$ and not $-1$. To start with, at $0$, the summation property gives us 0:

$$
\frac{0^{\underline{-1}}}{-1} = \frac{\frac{0}{0+1}}{-1} = 0
$$

Then $1$ is

$$
\frac{1^{\underline{-1}}}{-1} = \frac{\frac{1}{1+1}}{-1} = -\frac12
$$

and $2$ is
$$
\frac{2^{\underline{-1}}}{-1} = \frac{\frac{1}{2+1}}{-1} = -\frac13
$$

And so on tending towards -1 for larger $n$. As I understand it (the subtraction vertical bar notation) if $n$ is, say, $2$ (a long way from infinity to be sure) then we'd get $-\frac13 - 0 = -\frac13$. And so on getting closer to $-1$ as best I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a negative sign. The vertical bar notation
$$f(k)\;\Biggr|_0^n$$ means: evaluate $f(k)$ at $k=n$ and $k=0$, and subtract the two, obtaining $$f(n) - f(0).$$ Using this convention, you get
$$\frac{k^\underline{-1}}{-1}\;\Biggr|_0^n=\frac{n^\underline{-1}}{-1}-\frac{0^\underline{-1}}{-1}=\frac{-1}{n+1}-(-1).$$ The first term tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. As for the second term, the two negative signs combine to give $+1$.